# How to access the html select value in php, html embedded in php

Tags: php

I've written a php code where i need html select.

```
function x()
$sqlqry="select distinct(field_place_of_project_value) as Location from field_revision_field_place_of_project ";
  $htmlStr= '<select name="country" id="countrySelection" onclick="getCategoriesList()">  <option>All</option>';
$result = db_query($sqlqry);        
foreach ($result as $row_table) {
    $htmlStr .= '<option>' . t($row_table->Location) . '</option>';
} //for loop end
$htmlStr .= '</select>';

return $htmlStr;
```

From the inserted select tag, i need to get the selected value

Comment: I hope you aren't using that snippet of code in a production environment; it's chockful of potential problems.

Comment: What `getCategoriesList()` does?

Comment: what is the use of t() function in t($row_table->Location)

Comment: please provide result of print_r($_POST) when you submit this form

Answer (score 0):

When you POST the form you will get the value in $_POST['country'] in php.

Comment: why do we need the form. Don't we get the value without posting it to form?

Comment: PHP is server side. And what client selects is on client side. Unless you send some data to Server, you cannot get it on PHP. You can also use ajax if you don't want the page to post a form.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this `return $htmlStr;` write `echo $htmlStr;` because it is not function.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form in PHP, all the data submitted are accessible via the superglobal variable **$_POST**; each input value is accessed by $_POST["input_name_attribute"]. 
     Therefore, to access that particular data, you use $_POST["country"]. 
 
     Hope this helps.

Comment: why do we need the form. Don't we get the value without posting it to form?

Comment: No; the server cannot receive the data entered by the user without the form being posted to the server.

Comment: Is there any way of getting it without posting it

Comment: Getting it where? You can use Javascript to get it in the client, but it has to post it for the server to do anything with it.

Comment: @Barmar is correct; you can obtain the value via JavaScript and use it on the client side, but if you plan to use it on the server side, you'll have to post it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **problem** in your script you were not adding value attribute to the options tag, now when you submit this form you'll get selected value in your $_POST/$_GET  array.

```
$sqlqry="select distinct(field_place_of_project_value) as Location from field_revision_field_place_of_project ";

$htmlStr= '<select name="country" id="countrySelection" onclick="getCategoriesList()">  <option>All</option>';

$result = db_query($sqlqry);        
foreach ($result as $row_table) {
    $htmlStr .= '<option value=". $row_table->Location .'">' . t($row_table->Location) . '</option>';
} //for loop end

$htmlStr .= '</select>';

return $htmlStr;
```

Comment: I believe that if an `<option>` doesn't have a `value` attribute, it uses the text content of the element by default. So while this is preferable, it isn't required.

Comment: @Barmar : you are right if value is not given it consider the label as value